# How to grep summarized value from excel cell range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to get summarize information from the following sheet. I don't know how to summarize this information.

[image]

My scenario is like this.

If I input ***-6***, I want to find my target value in this range.

[image]

If I input ***70***, I want to show only the following record.

[image]

So, summary is like this. I will be key-in one by one

```
.=
-6
70
```

If I hit enter, result want to display like;

```
865.5   70   155    4
```

[image]

Please help me to provide sample solution or sample function to solve this.

Comment: _If I input -6, I want to find my target value in this range_  
How is **target** value decided. Is -6 used as an index into the rows of data.

Comment: @kingchris Column + 3 and Row + 9. E.g **-6** is A11. So, Column is A11+3 and Row is A11+9 Row

Comment: No sorry. I don't understand the thinking here. Perhaps edit your question to clarify how these minus figures offset into your rows and columns and then why the positive 70 does not. There are quite a few cell range functions in Excel but if we don't know what you want its difficult to advise on a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to *grep* in Excel is AutoFilter.  You can use it to view subsets of data based on criteria.

However, to use it your data would require re-organization. The criteria must appear in **columns** rather than **rows**.  So you would a column for *-6, -7, -8, -9, -10*, etc.